# angular2 bootstrap3 dropdown error

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

[image]

Hi developers , My Angular2 project i try bootstrap dropdown "Mail" is working but 
second dropdown not working

Comment: Where is second dropdown ?

Comment: What is the error? Not working means? Can you please add your code, that you tried to the question??? Also are you able to see any console errors in the browser - if you think there is an error?

Comment: https://i.hizliresim.com/29JPAj.jpg and click Mail button not open others link my friend

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Mail button is second dropdown

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai İletişim Operasyonları button is working but Mail not working

Comment: @user2800554, it is working for you my solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of nested dropdown.

```js
$('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```